# How do I access form properties with Invoke, but with object parameter in C#?

Tags: c#, oop, parameters, invoke

I couldn't describe the title of my question the best,I'm sorry.
Currently,I use Invoke to access the properties on my form,It works perfect,but I have a function for each property,which is quite not comfortable.

```
    public static void EnableLogin(int enabled)
    {
        var form = Form.ActiveForm as FormMain;
        if (form != null)
            form.EnableLogin = enabled;
    }

    public static void EnableConfirm(int enabled)
    {
        var form = Form.ActiveForm as FormMain;
        if (form != null)
            form.EnableConfirm = enabled;
    }

    public static void EnableRetry(int enabled)
    {
        var form = Form.ActiveForm as FormMain;
        if (form != null)
            form.EnableRetry = enabled;
    }

    public static void EnableTABLogin(int enabled)
    {
        var form = Form.ActiveForm as FormMain;
        if (form != null)
            form.EnableTABLogin = enabled;
    }
```

Each of these functions looks like that

```
    public int EnableLogin
    {
        set
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    if (value == 0)
                        this.btnLogin.Enabled = false;
                    else
                        this.btnLogin.Enabled = true;
                });
            }
            else
            {
                if (value == 0)
                    this.btnLogin.Enabled = false;
                else
                    this.btnLogin.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

My question is,can't I do it like that

```
    public static void EnableObject(object name)
    {
        var form = Form.ActiveForm as FormMain;
        if (form != null)
            form.Enable + name = enabled;
    }
```

It's definitely not that way,I couldn't think of something more OO,but instead of writing tons of functions with same code,can't I use one by passing the object I'd like to change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a method that takes an delegate parameter describing the action to perform. Then you could get rid of the repeated code.

Here is an example: I create a public method called PerformAction on my form. It takes an Action<MainForm> delegate as argument; this delegate describes the action that should be taken.

The instance method should be used when possible, but for completeness I created a static version that gets the Form instance from Form.ActiveForm.

The code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinFormTest
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public void PerformAction(Action<MainForm> action)
        {
            if (InvokeRequired)
                Invoke(action,this);
            else
                action(this);
        }

        public static void PerformActionOnMainForm(Action<MainForm> action)
        {
            var form = ActiveForm as MainForm;
            if ( form!= null)
                form.PerformAction(action);
        }
    }
}
```

And can then be used like this from another thread:

```
    MainForm.PerformActionOnMainForm(form => form.Text = "My form");
    // The action can also be a code block or a method:
    MainForm.PerformActionOnMainForm(form =>
                                         {
                                             form.Width = 200;
                                             form.Height = 300;
                                             form.Left = 100;
                                             form.Top = 200;
                                         });
```

PerformAction could also be made generic so you can use it on any of your forms. Then the signature would be:

```
public void PerformAction<T>(Action<T> action) 
    where T : Form 
    { 
        ... 
    }
```

It would make sense to declare it like this if you have a common base class that is shared amongst your forms. Alternatively, you could create a helper class containing the method.

Comment: I'm very interested,please do so.

Comment: Very nice,but it's not working.It gives me an error on that line "Misc.PerformActionOnMainForm(FormMain => FormMain.groupMain.Enabled = true);" Error "FormMain.groupMain' is inaccessible due to its protection level".I Don't want to change the modified to public,but i tried it - exception,not working

Comment: Actually it works if everything is "protected internal".
Great,thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657037/why-the-overhead-for-multi-threaded-access-to-wpf-ui-controls) but for WPF, the principle is the same though. Modifying the answer that was provided to me by Jon skeet for your question you could use something like this:

```
public static void InvokeIfNecessary(Form form, MethodInvoker action)
{    
     if (form.InvokeRequired)    
     {        
          form.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, action);    
     }    
     else    
     {        
          action();    
     }
}

public static void EnableLogin(int enabled)    
{        
    var form = Form.ActiveForm as FormMain;        
    if (form != null)            
        InvokeIfNecessary(form, delegate { form.btnLogin.Enabled = (enabled != 0) });    
}
```

Edit: Changed from using form.Dispatcher.

Comment: This also describes the basic principle, the code is wrong however. form.Dispatcher does not exist in WinForms.

Comment: Yeah,also you cant write "form.InvokeIfNecessary(form, delegate { form.btnLogin.Enabled = (enabled != 0) });" brackets {} cannot be used.Also I'd also like to see something similiar for the EnableLogin method.Why not EnableProperty method with parameter : the property.

Comment: Ok I edited the eg. to remove the Dispatcher reference since that's a WPF thing. In regards to the use of the EnableLogin property I cut the setter out as in the eg. it was a lot of code to set a bool and can be done in a single line. If you need to do more in the setter it could still be used.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the reused functionality into two sperate static methods (one extension) which will greatly simplify what you have in the static helpers and properties.

```
public static class FormHelpers
{
  public static void InvokeOnActive<TForm>(Action<TForm> action)
    where TForm : Form
  {
    TForm activeForm = Form.ActiveForm as TForm;
    if (activeForm != null)
      activeForm.InvokeEx(f => { action(f); return f; });
  }
}

public static class ControlExtensions
{
  public static TResult InvokeEx<TControl, TResult>(this TControl control,
                                              Func<TControl, TResult> func)
    where TControl : Control
  {
    if (control.InvokeRequired)
      return (TResult)control.Invoke(func, control);
    else
      return func(control);
  }
}
```

And for your properties:

```
public int EnableLogin
{
  set { this.InvokeEx(f => f.btnLogin.Enabled = value == 0); }
}
```

And for your static helpers:

```
public static void EnableLogin(int enabled)
{
  FormHelpers.InvokeOnActive<FormMain>(f => f.EnableLogin = enabled);
}
```